# How to send header to graphql using graphql screen?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have nodejs application with graphql.

How to send token header using graphql screen? (attached picture)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add headers in the lower left of the graphQL client.

[image]

[image]